# How to correctly initialize a function in React?

Tags: reactjs

tell me, please, how to solve the following problem correctly?
I have a certain component, there is a control above, when I click on it, setState is triggered. I need to call the function this.setScrollLeft () in which I set to the selected node (ref) in this case the cleavage position.
Here is my implementation, but I am sure that there is a better solution:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScoreCell, getScoreTheme } from 'components/scores';

class LeaderboardPlayerResult extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.containerWidth = 198;

        this.data = this.props.data;
        this.playerResultRef = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.element = this.playerResultRef.current;
        this.element.scrollLeft = this.containerWidth;
    }

    setScrollLeft = () => {
        if (this.element) {
            this.element.scrollLeft = this.containerWidth;
        }
    };

    playerResult = () => {
        if (this.data.playOffHoles) {
            return (
                this.data.playOffHoles.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div
                            className="leaderboard__player-result-row-wrapper"
                            key={index}
                        >
                            <div className="leaderboard__player-result-row">
                                <div className="leaderboard__player-result-cell">{item.holeId}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="leaderboard__player-result-row">
                                <div className="leaderboard__player-result-cell">{item.holePar}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="leaderboard__player-result-row">
                                <div className="leaderboard__player-result-cell leaderboard__player-result-cell--score">
                                    <ScoreCell
                                        childCss='tee-times-card__score'
                                        theme={getScoreTheme(item.playOffParScore)}
                                    >{item.playOffParScore}</ScoreCell>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })
            );
        }
    };

    render() {
        console.log('LeaderboardPlayerResult render');
        this.setScrollLeft();
        return (
            <div
                className="leaderboard__player-result"
                ref={this.playerResultRef}
            >
                {this.playerResult()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `setState` triggered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place to put `this.setScrollLeft()` is inside the `componentDidUpdate` method.

You are already calling this method (`this.setScrollLeft()`) inside `componentDidMount`, what is right. Now, you could put another call into `componentDidUpdate` and it will work pretty much as it is working by now because `componentDidUpdate` is called before `render`.

The final outcome will be the same, however, you are separating the concerns: `render` only render the components and the other methods deal with your business logic.

If you are not sure about `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`, see these excerpts from the official React.js documentation:

[componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering.

[componentDidUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.